# Microsoft Teams conversations storage

Tags: office365, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I am trying to find out where exactly the Teams Channel conversations are stored in the Teams mailbox. I need to get the conversations from the mailbox using EWS API.

Using EWSEditor I can see that, posts in the private channel and 1:1 conversations are present in the folder "TeamsMessagesData" present inside the Teams mailbox. But somehow I am not able to find messages posted on a public channel. Is there any different location I should be querying to get posts in the public channel?

Comment: Why not just use the Graph API to get this info?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Channel messages aren't stored in the users mailbox only the P2P chats are and only for compliance reasons. If you want the channel messages you would need to access the Team's mailbox directly or look at using another API like the Microsoft Graph to Enumerate/Search for them in Teams directly.

Comment: It was my mistake. I misread info available in EWSEditor. Verified that 1:1 and 1:n chats are stored in users mailbox and channel posts are stored in Teams mailbox. Marking this as answer to help anyone in similar situation.